# ChronoUnit.MONTHS: inconsistency between addTo() and between()

Tags: java, time, java-time, jsr310

In some cases, `ChronoUnit.MONTHS` perform math on dates inconsistently depending if we add or subtract. Corner case is when we e.g. add 1 month to a date `2023-01-31`. I understand there is no single, correct answer if the result should be `2023-02-28` or `2023-03-01`. However, I would expect the same API to at least use the same assumptions, which is not the case here:

```java
var d1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-01-31T10:00:00Z");

// add 1 month
var d2 = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.addTo(d1, 1);
// add 23 hours
d2 = ChronoUnit.HOURS.addTo(d2, 23);

// subtract
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(d1, d2)); // 0
```

Apparently, `addTo()` assumes 1 month from `2023-01-31 10:00` is `2023-02-28 10:00`, however, `between()` assumes one full month ends at `2023-03-01 10:00`.

Is this a bug? Do I miss or misunderstand something?

BTW, `d1.plusMonths(1)` works in the same way as `addTo()` and this behavior is even clearly documented. `between()` seems to be inconsistent with other operations.

EDIT:

I understand the date math is tricky, it isn't exactly "math", calendar dates don't flow linearly and we can't treat them as adding/subtracting just numbers. But still, I find some examples extremely counter-intuitive:

- Between `2023-01-31 11:00` and `2023-03-01 10:00` there are `0` full months, while there is literally a full calendar month between these dates.
- There are `5` months between `2023-05-31 11:00` and `2023-12-01 10:00`, but if we add `6` months to the first date, we get... `2023-11-30 11:00`, so older date than the one that is `5` months away.

Comment: @Sweeper I used the same code as above, but with `Period.between()` (and type conversion) at the end and it returned 1 month. But well, `Period` works on full dates, so I guess it is not comparable - I removed it from the question. And yes, I know `between()` is something a little different and it is not entirely subtraction, but still... it feels strange to me that e.g. `d1 + 1 < d2`, `d1 < d2 - 1`, but distance between them is `<1`. It feels strange if we ask: "How many months between d1 and d2?". "5". "Then let's add 6 months to d1" and as a result we get a date which is older than d2...

Comment: I don’t think a fully consistent way of doing month arithmetic exists. Because of months having different lengths. Different date libraries do it differently, and no library that I have seen has a fully consistent way of doing it in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. It is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) as follows:

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of
> complete units between the two temporals. For example, the amount in
> hours between the times 11:30 and 13:29 will only be one hour as it is
> one minute short of two hours.

In the following code, d2 becomes *2023-02-28T10:00Z* but when it calculates the difference as per the above documentation, it would have counted the difference as 1 if a date such as *2023-02-31T10:00:00Z* existed. If not, it counts the difference as 1 for the next day which is ***2023-03-01T10:00:00Z***.

```
var d1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2023-01-31T10:00:00Z");
var d2 = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.addTo(d1, 1);
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(d1, d2)); // 0
```

When you add 23 hours in the next statement, it becomes *2023-03-01T09:00Z* which is one hour less than ***2023-03-01T10:00:00Z***; therefore it does not reach the point to count the difference as 1 month.

```
d2 = ChronoUnit.HOURS.addTo(d2, 23); // 2023-03-01T09:00Z
```

Had you added 24 hours, it would have become ***2023-03-01T10:00:00Z*** and given you the difference as 1.

**This behaviour is consistent across all the time units.**

Comment: Yes, I understand what is going on and how it is calculated. "if a date such as 2023-02-31T10:00:00Z existed. If not, it counts the difference as 1 for the **next day**". And this is exactly what I mean. If the date doesn't exists, `addTo()` takes the nearest **previous day**, while `between()` takes the **next day**. This is the inconsistency I mean.